# SQL for summing only new values

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, sum

i have a table like this

```
NAME    VALUE
-----------------
bla      1
bla      2
bla      2
bla      3
bla      1
bla      4
bla      2
```

How can i do a sum  of ONLY different values , and ignore the repeating values (is it possible?)? 
Something like this :

```
 SELECT SUM(??condition?? value) as total FROM table
```

And the sum should be 10.

Thank you!

Comment: "ONLY different values " what is the selection criteria?

Comment: Is the value in the name column always the same? What do you want to happen when you have different names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT SUM(value) as total FROM (SELECT DISTINCT value FROM table) tmp;
```

Source: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?97,203188,203787#msg-203787

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT value) as total FROM table
```

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum

The second solution is better because it does not create temporary table. Therefore it is faster.

Comment: The two solutions you've posted are not equivalent in general so saying one is faster than the other is not really a good reason to choose between them. They will give different results when the name is not a constant field.

Comment: you could shorten the first subquery to "SELECT DISTINCT value FROM table", right?

Answer (score 6):

Wouldn't

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT value) FROM mytable;
```

do the trick?

Comment: yours is good but MartyIX was the first one to post :) so i gave him the check :)

Comment: +1 from me because you were the first to give a **correct** answer (the other answer was edited within the 5 minute limit, but it was after you had already posted your answer so you were the first).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to sum all distinct values then you can use DISTINCT:

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT value) AS total FROM yourtable
```

If you want to calculate a different sum for each name then add GROUP BY:

```
SELECT name, SUM(DISTINCT value) AS total 
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY name
```

Or to only consider a specific name:

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT value) AS total 
FROM yourtable
WHERE name = 'bla'
```